# IE 11 keeps requesting cached assets

Tags: http, internet-explorer, internet-explorer-11, browser-cache, cache-control

On any page load, IE keeps requesting all page assets (JS, CSS, images) again, the server keeps returning `304 Not Modified`. We hadn't anticipated this, so 20+ files get requested on every page load. We only see this on IE 11 (not Edge, FF or Chrome).

The below dialog seems to control this behaviour:

[image: IE settings]

On 1 PC I could get hold of this was also the currently set option (no domain policy, so could change that). However we can't require our customers to change this setting. The server returns the header like `Expires: Wed, 27 Mar 2019 19:56:43 GMT`, but IE seems to ignore it with this setting.

Do I understand correctly that with this setting it is impossible to have IE cache the assets for any period of time (be it half an hour)?

Answer (score 0):

The [Temporary Internet Files](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Temporary_Internet_Files) is a folder on Microsoft Windows which serves as the browser cache for Internet Explorer to cache pages and other multimedia content, such as video and audio files, from websites visited by the user. This allows such websites to load more quickly the next time they are visited. You can change it to "Automatically".

Besides, I suggest you could also try to open the F12 developer tools Network tab and check whether you have turned on [the "Always refresh from server" option](https://learn.microsoft.com/zh-cn/previous-versions/windows/internet-explorer/ie-developer/samples/dn255004(v%3dvs.85)).  This option is a toggle switch with on and off states. When on, Internet Explorer 11 downloads all page elements from the remote server, not from the browser cache.

And you could also check whether the request header, whether it contains [conditional Requests](https://blogs.msdn.microsoft.com/ieinternals/2010/07/08/understanding-conditional-requests-and-refresh/).